# Azure VM : How can I use VM B1s OS Disk for free?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have been using B1s VMs for a month and have upgraded to pay-as-you-go.
However, I checked that money was being paid from the OS disk when the instance was created.
Is there a way to replace it with a data disk(P6 free) or use it for free?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade the VM to pay-as-you-go, then it's not free. And you cannot replace the OS disk into the data disk. If you want to use it as free, just do not upgrade to pay-as-you-go when it's free.